# Native ionic geolocation sometimes not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Native ionic geolocation sometimes not working on few devices. Need to restart the device to work the geolocation.Geolocation works after restart the device.I am facing the issue on android version 5.0.2.

My code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/bindCallback';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Injectable()
export class LocationService {

  constructor (
    private geolocation: Geolocation
  ) { }

  getLocation(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.fromPromise (
      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
        maximumAge: 5 * 60 * 1000, // 5 minutes
        timeout: 30000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      })
    ).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      return Observable.throw(err);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats the error or what do you mean by not working ?

Comment: getting lat long undefined .

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding it with Ionic platform ready.

```
  constructor(public plt: Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then((readySource) => {
      console.log('Platform ready from', readySource);
      // Platform now ready, execute any required native code
    });
  }
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/

Comment: I am using a separate location server.